# How to prove a circle parameterization is injective?

Tags: line-integrals, arc-length

I'm set to calculate the arc length of a circle after a full revolution by using line integrals. This should be easy but im trying not to leave behind checking the hypothesis before i start. I made this parameterization of the curve:

$$\alpha (t)=\left ( 2\cdot cos(t),2\cdot sin(t),2 \right )$$

As i need $\alpha (t)$ to be a regular parameterization of the curve, one of the checkmarks is for it to be injective within the interval $\left ( a,b \right )$ in this case $\left ( 0,2\pi \right )$.

It's clear to see that a circle is a simple curve, as it doesn't cross itself besides on it's borders.

Nevertheless, i'm trying to solve it analytically:

So, being $t_1$ and $t_2$ real numbers which belong to $\left ( 0,2\pi \right )$,$\alpha (t)$ is injective if:

$$\alpha (t_1)=\alpha (t_2)\Rightarrow t_1 =t_2$$

This is where i'm stuck:

$$cos(t_1) =  cos(t_2)$$

$$sin(t_1) = sin(t_2)$$

Taking the inverse of either cosine or sine in the respective equation would solve it, but i think that the yielded solution would only be true for an interval where the function from which you want to use this said inverse is injective (Because it needs to be -along being surjective- in order to apply it's inverse). This interval would be for example, $(0,\pi/2)$ but then the problem here is that i can't prove injectivity for the whole curve for $t\in \left ( 0,2\pi \right )$, just for this portion. Correct me if i'm wrong in any of these assumptions :)

I could take this interval for $\alpha (t)$, calculate the length and then mulitply it by four because its symmetric.

The thing is, i want to be able to solve this system of equations and prove $\alpha (t)$ is injective for $t\in \left ( 0,2\pi \right )$, while not taking a shortcut like benefit from its symmetric properties.

I remember i saw in class a way to solve this algebraically but i cant recall how.

Comment: Are you familiar with the representation of $\sin$ and $\cos$ as exponential polynomials (ie. $\sin(x),\cos(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{A}} a_n e^{ixn}$)? If not, what definition are we working with?

Comment: @SebastiánP.Pincheira Not quite. I've studied hyperbolic functions which are closely related but not in depth. I'm currently at a multivariable calculus course and our current subjects are curves, parameterizations and line integrals. One definition would be the arc length of any curve whose parameterizations is regular. This is $length(\gamma)=\int_{a}^{b}\left \| \alpha '(t)) \right \|dt$. Alpha being a parameterizations of gamma whose domain is the interval $I=\left [ a,b \right ]$ .

Comment: @SebastiánP.Pincheira Ran out of characters.  The other definition would be regular parameterizations of a curve. These are parameterizations that are continous on $\left[a,b\right]$, injective and piecewise class $C^1$ on $\left(a,b\right)$, and whose derivatives are different from zero for $\left(a,b\right)$. So, as i need the parameterization to be injective on  $\left(0,2\pi\right)$ i tried to prove it but couldn't. As a side note, i don't recall using exponential polynomials to solve the system of equations. I think we just used a trigonometric identity. My memory's a little hazy.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant the definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ you are working with. If you want an analytical proof of the fact that $(\sin,\cos)$ is injective in $(0,2\pi)$ you are going to need an analytical definition (that's why I mentioned $\sin$ as an exponential linear combination).